# Closing buttons after 3 seconds javafx

Tags: java, button, javafx, timer

I have a grid with buttons. 1 to 3 buttons are activated randomly in my grid and I am trying to close buttons that are activated, after 3 seconds.
I tryed using a timeline but it only closed 1 button. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "... close buttons..."?

Anyway, whatever it means you can do it after certain delay using a simple class like:

```
    private class DelayedTrigger extends Task<Void> {

    private final long delay;
    private Runnable onTriggered;

    public DelayedTrigger(long delay, Runnable onTriggered) {
        this.delay = delay;
        this.onTriggered = onTriggered;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        if (onTriggered != null) {
            onTriggered.run();
        }
    }
```

Then, when your button gets "activated", you just:

```
    DelayedTrigger activeTrigger = new DelayedTrigger(3000, () -> myActivatedButton.close());
    new Thread(activeTrigger).start();
```

And if you change your mind later (e.g. because of some event coming after 2 seconds), you can still cancel the trigger by calling:

```
    activeTrigger.cancel();
```

There will probably be some better (built in) solution but this is what I use.